# Jenkins trying to extract latest git tag... not working

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I'm working on a *Jenkins* pipeline.
Context: Multi-branch pipeline is activated for all repos.

My problem: I'm trying to extract the latest *git-tag* from the repository, while the pipeline is doing CI/CD stuff for the feature branch.

I have tried many ways of getting the *git-tag*, however whatever method I use, I always get either `null` or something like 'unknown option ...' returned.

Here the relevant code block:

```
script {
  def tag = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git tag --sort=-creatordate | head -n 1").trim()
  echo "tag: ${tag}"
  ...other script here...
}
```

Running the git command from the command line works, returning what I expect it to return.
Does anyone have an idea why this does not work?

Comment: This is *probably* a Jenkins issue rather than a Git one, but since you mention multiple repositories: if you are running a command from. e.g., a Git hook, the environment variable `$GIT_DIR` may be set to the path of the Git repository. In this case `cd`-ing to another working tree with a different repository has an unexpected effect: the new working tree location is used as the working tree, but the old repository continues to be used as the repository. That is, you must *unset* `GIT_DIR` before cd-ing about.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking out a git repo using `checkout scm` or something? It almost sounds like there is no local git repo. You might need to put the full pipeline instead of just the "relevant" code block

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same issue. This might come from the fact that your jenkins pipeline fetch your repository without fetching tags (wich is the default behaviour). To also fetch tags you need to add the following to your pipeline configuration:
In Branch Source Behaviours add **"Advanced clone behaviours"** and check the **"Fetch tags"** option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).